# how to get row index of selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my view
[image]

im trying to access row index using this method

```
$("input.deliverQty").focusout(function (e) {
    var table = document.getElementById('invoiceDetailTbl');
    var DeliverQty = $(this).val();
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('rowIndex');
    //var OrderQty = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.payingAmt').val();
    var OrderQty = table.rows[parseInt(rowId) + 1].cells[2].childNodes[0].data;
```

but result was undefined
[image]

i'm append my table like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].itemDetails.length; i++) {
                itmCode = data[0].itemDetails[i].item_Code;
                itmName = data[0].itemDetails[i].item_Name;
                OQty = parseInt(data[0].itemDetails[i].item_Qty);
                //netAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Net_Amt).toFixed(2);
                //paidAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Paid_Amt).toFixed(2);
                //balance = (parseFloat(netAmt) - parseFloat(paidAmt)).toFixed(2); //id = "damt['+i+']"
                $("#invoiceDetailTbl tbody").append("<tr id=" + i + ">" + "<td>" + itmCode + "</td>" + "<td>" + itmName + "</td>" + "<td>" + OQty + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<input type="text" class="deliverQty form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Deliver Qty" id="dqty">' + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                //noOfItems = parseInt(noOfItems) + parseInt(OQty);
                //noOfProducts = parseInt(noOfProducts) + 1;
            }
```

Comment: Show your HTML also.

Comment: You have loaded jQuery, why don't you use it?

Comment: var index_of_current = $("table tr").index($("currentTR"));

Comment: the fairly important part here is the HTML structure, but you did not post that important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowIndex` is not an attribute, so try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();

jQuery(function() {
  $('tr input').each(function() {
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('rowIndex');
    log('attr:  ' + rowId);
    rowId = $(this).closest('tr').prop('rowIndex');
    log('prop: ' + rowId);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: your previous answer also give solution to me